# When I try to open .html file in chrome it ocassionally open repository

Tags: html, google-chrome

[it divide my html file on 2 different files 1)is repository 2)is just some loading page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bV2od.png)

same error with pdf files but it divides on 3 files

It works in Firefox.

Google Chrome is set to be my main browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the version of chrome that you use don't support what you're doing but its just my random guess , you can try to use live server of some IDE like VScode and see if the problem persist.

Comment: Yeah it worked! Just update browser, sorry i cant upvote in case of low reputation(

Comment: No problems dude, I am glad it helped.